# Grub doesn't appear at boot time

Tags: grub2, ubuntu-gnome

I have only Ubuntu gnome installed in my system.

When I start my laptop it is directly booting to Ubuntu gnome.  Instead, I want to see the grub menu every time I switch on my laptop.

Comment: show us your /etc/default/grub

Comment: you could edit grub menu: gksu gedit /etc/default/grub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

take a look at your `/etc/default/grub`.

There should b a line like `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0`,
change it to `#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0`.

And change `GRUB_TERMINAL=console` to  `#GRUB_TERMINAL=console`.

after this changes you'll see the normal grub menu.

Comment: I could not find the file /boot/grub.conf

Comment: I found a similar one in /boot/grub/grub.cfg , but there is no line similar to the one you mentioned above. I am using ubuntu-gnome 14.04

Comment: I am using Ubuntu gnome 14.04

Comment: ya sure just give me your email id

Comment: i have sent you the message :)